Reverting a BigQuery table pushed to by Pub/Sub to a backup
I have a BigQuery table I stream updates to from Pub/Sub topic via push subscription writing to it with the topic schema.
At some point, I backed up the table with:
CREATE TABLE `my-dataset.my-table-backup`
CLONE `my-dataset.my-table`;

then added and delete some records via some other process from my-dataset.my-table.
Now I'd like to revert to the backup. I tried:

Changed my pubsub subscription to "pull" type
Renaming the tables:

ALTER TABLE `my-dataset.my-table` RENAME TO `my-dataset.my-table-old`
ALTER TABLE `my-dataset.my-table-backup` RENAME TO `my-dataset.my-table`

But even after hours, still getting error:
Cannot rename my-dataset.my-table because it has streaming data.
I would rather not drop and re-create this table since it has a complex nested json schema, partitioning, and clustering. How can I restore this table to backup with minimal downtime from the subscription being off?

Hello @Wassadamo, as mentioned in this documentation If you want to rename a table that has data streaming into it, you must stop the streaming and wait for BigQuery to indicate that streaming is not in use.

Yes and according to this documentation on push subscriptions, the way you stop the streaming is to edit the subscription and change to "pull" type. Which I did, and waited about ~5 hours. Is there a request I can make to verify whether streaming is not in use? Or may I edit this property more directly?

Hi @Wassadamo, has your issue been resolved renaming table after streaming stopped?
